# Missing Classes and Methods in ASP.net MVC 2

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I download asp.net mvc2 preview 2 days back. I've just started studying MVC. I tried to create a page to display Product details from AdventureWorksLT database. There is an Image in it (stored as byte[]). After googling for sometime I got some help and a few links from SO and other sites. There is one very nice post about doing this with helper methods [here](http://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2008/05/ASPNET-MVC-custom-ActionResult.aspx). I picked the code from this page but then VS complained that some methods are missing like

```
HtmlHelper.BuildUrlFromExpression
```

I googled again and got to [this page](http://forums.asp.net/t/1263007.aspx). Now the problem was:

```
LinkBuilder.BuildParameterValuesFromExpression: The name "LinkBuilder" does not 
  exists in current context.
```

Please help me to find these methods or alternatives to them.

Comment: Hmm, LinkBuilder is in the ASP.NET MVC Futures Assembly (Microsoft.Web.Mvc). Have they folded that into MVC 2 yet?

Comment: nope not yet and there is only Microsoft.Web.Mvc.Build assembly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Futures assemblies are available from CodePlex.

MVC 1 RTM:
http://aspnet.codeplex.com/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=24471

MVC 2 Preview 1:
http://aspnet.codeplex.com/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=30886

MVC 2 Preview 2 hasn't been released yet, so there is no Futures assembly for it.  When it is released, the Futures assembly will also be located on CodePlex.

Comment: I've already downloaded and am using those. Still thanks for answer!